# How to use Bootstrap Collapse in Blazor app

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I am just trying to create a small prototype application in Visual Studio using .Net 5/Blazor server app,  where I need to have Bootstrap collapse functionality in a Blazor component - this would contain a separate Blazor component when expanded.

I am trying to avoid where possible to use JavaScript or jQuery in the prototype as much as possible. However, I can see that in some cases such as Bootstrap Collapse I may need to do this. I would like to have code local to the component if possible, but ok to having a .js file containing common helper functions if needed.

The code below gives an example with some ideas on how I might do this - does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work.

```
    <div class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="ViewDetails" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="details">
            this is some text for a button
        </div>
        <div class="collapse" id="details">
            this is the details screen for this record
        </div>
    
    @code {
     private async void ViewDetails()
        {
            // Button click indicates an event so should be able to get redraw to occur.  
    
            // Some mechanism to change the toggle state without calling javascript (dhtml style)
            // Use a boolean to change the ARIA state or something like that
            _viewDetails = (_viewDetails == false) ? true : false;
            this.StateHasChanged();
            
            // Or, call inline jquery to toggle control (preferred) something like.
            await _JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("$('#details).collapse('toggle');", "");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two solutions I used. I have upvoted replies above as they provided the info to resolve the issue.

solution 1:
In this solution I used the button click to toggle the visibility of a div tag (as above) to display the component.

Solution 2: (the one I used). Is to download the bootstrap bundle and extract it into my wwwroot directory (this contains all of the files required including popper). I then added a .js and .css reference in _host.cshtml to bootstrap.bundle.min.js and bootstrap.min.css respectively.

```
     <!-- using a bootstrap container with a unique id e.g. entity@1 -->
    <div class=container-fluid collapse" id="entity@(myid)">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-12">
          <!-- the component that is displayed when the collapse is toggled -->
          <MyComponent componentId=@myid />
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>

The component is 
   @if (componentId > 0)
   {
      <!-- do razor code -->
   }
[Parameter] public Int32 componentId {get; set;}
```

Comment: Have u been able to add unit test to this behavior? I'm kinda struggling with this

Comment: I don't use unit testing, but yes, it works. I updated my above post with my current solution.

Answer (score 7):

You could create a component dedicated to doing this. This will however not have the smooth transition from open to close as Bootstrap collapse. Notice this is wrapped in a Bootstrap card - use can simply remove that if not needed.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components

<div class="pb-3">
   <div class="card">
       <div class="card-header">
            <button class="btn btn-link" style="color: black; text-decoration: none" @onclick="Toggle">
               <b>@CardHeaderTitle</b>
            </button>
            @CardHeader
            <button @onclick="Toggle" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm float-right">
                <span class="@BtnClass"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        @if (ShowCardBody)
        {
            <div class="card-body">
                @CardBody
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CardBody { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment CardHeader { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string CardHeaderTitle { get; set; }


    [Parameter] public bool ShowCardBody { get; set; } = false;
    public string BtnClass => ShowCardBody ? "oi oi-collapse-up" : "oi oi-collapse-down";
    public void Toggle()
    {
        ShowCardBody = !ShowCardBody;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
<CollapsibleCard CardHeaderTitle="Title">
    <CardHeader>
        ...
    </CardHeader>
    <CardBody>
        ...
    </CardBody>
</CollapsibleCard>
```

If you would like to use Bootstrap collapse try out the approach use a data-target explained [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/collapse/). This worked for me previous. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: This is the way. Can I suggest a pure css animation on the transition.

Comment: Hi thanks,  I will look into the data-target - do you have another example? - when I try using the example, it does not work.   I am trying to avoid having to re-write functionality that already exists in Bootstrap.

Comment: Did you remember to add the scripts necessary for Bootstrap JavaScript to your index.html(client-side Blazor) or _Host.cshtml (server-side Blazor)? This is not shipped by default with the Blazor template in Visual Studio. Have a look here for Bootstrap 4.5 https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/#js. 

I just tried to create a new Blazor project and included the scripts, then the collapse data-target example from the Bootstrap documentation worked.

Comment: no I didn't - but will try.  The app does not have internet access, so cannot use the CDN links.  I have installed using NuGet - do you have example script/links to add to _hosts.cshtml for this - the bootstrap site is missing this information.

Comment: There's instructions at [learn.microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1189167/blazor-visual-studio-sample-template-missing-boots) for how to install boostrap.min.js to the project via Visual Studio